# pipのアップグレードができない

Tags: python, pip

pip自体をアップグレードするために

```
pip install -U pip
```

と実行したら以下のエラーがでました。

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (21.3.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.3.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-9p0nuyo8\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip3.7.exe
   from C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-9p0nuyo8\pip3.7.exe
  Moving to c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-9p0nuyo8\pip3.exe
  Moving to c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\pip-21.3.1.dist-info\
   from c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\~ip-21.3.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\pip\
   from c:\users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 413, in run
    pycompile=options.compile,
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 81, in install_given_reqs
    pycompile=pycompile,
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 810, in install
    requested=self.user_supplied,
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 737, in install_wheel
    requested=requested,
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 646, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 428, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 427, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 417, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 317, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 247, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 396, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

PowerShellは

```
c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

にしろと言っていると思いコピペで再実行したのですが、全く同じエラーが発生してアップグレードができませんでした。

どのように解決したらよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんなほぼ同様な現象の記事を見つけました。
[pip｜アップデートでエラーが出た話](https://note.com/mnyacat_noob/n/n74af63d1ade9)

更に元となる記事はこちら。
[Document Windows 10 update solution #8450](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8450)

細かい版数は違いますが、発生している現象のログがだいたい同じと思われます。

両方の記事で解決方法は以下を実行すること、となっています。

> ```
> python -m pip uninstall pip
> python -m ensurepip
> python -m pip install -U pip
> ```

試してみてください。

Comment: まさに探していた記事です。どうやらバグのようで指示通りに実行したら無事解決しました。本当に本当にありがとうございます。